# Панель редактора на сайте 1с битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Как включить панель редактирования элементов на странице, там где есть "Создать страницу", "Создать раздел", "Режим правки" и т.д. Если в админке авторизован и из неё перехожу на вкладку "Сайт", то никакой панели на сайте не добавляется.

Comment: а к какой группе пользователей вы относитесь? если не к админской, но Вам нужна панель, тогда администратор должен настроить в настройках "Главного модуля" отображение панели для Вашей группы. Так же нужно проверить код шаблона прописано ли в нем подключение панели в файле `header.php` `<div id="panel"><? $APPLICATION->ShowPanel(); ?></div>`

Comment: а если к админской?

Comment: тогда проверяйте наличие подключения панели в коде.